# caption in a tikz object

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, labels

I created markov's chain using `tikz` package. Now I would add to to it caption and label but I got error.How can I add a caption and a label to a tikz object?

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The question as you stated it is way to broad to give a meaningful answer. By the way, did you include your TikZ picture in a `figure` environment?

Comment: no I didn't include in a figure environment

Comment: Then I suggest: `\begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\caption{whatever}\label{fig:my_fav_tikz}\end{figure}`. That should do the trick. `:)`

Comment: Ok now it works...I simply add figure environment

Comment: @Mazzy it's not mandatory to use a `figure` environment; it depends on whether you want the object to float or not. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to use floating environments, you will need to include the TikZ picture in a `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...% TikZ code goes here
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{whatever}
\label{f‌​ig:my_fav_tikz}
\end{figure}
```

If you don't want floats, see Gonzalo Medina's answer.

Comment: Well, my answer also includes the float case.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that... I'll delete my answer.

Comment: can't delete - been accepted...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the object to float, you can use, for example, a `minipage`  and `\captionof` from the `caption` package.

If you want the object to be treated as a floating object, you can enclose it within a `figure` environment.

A simple example illustrating both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tikz circle}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{A tikz circle}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `minipage` may be better than `center`, as that prohibits a pagebreak between figure and caption.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're right. Change made. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the first way you in your answer, the tikzpicture and the caption are OK, but strangely the picture appear another place, this is to say it does follow orders of the article. So , can you help me Gonzalo?

Comment: @Alex Sure, but we need the code, otherwise little help can be provided. Please open a follow-up question and provide there a minimal version of a document (like the one in my answer) illustrating the problem; you can also provide a link to this answer to provide some background.

Comment: thX, I know where the problem lies